# Problem with loading a add to cart button into silder

Tags: php, ce-1.9.0.1, addtocart

I have a problem with adding the add to cart button. Whenever I add the add to cart button the all of the sliders disapear from page. This is the example where I use the add to cart button .

```
    <h2>Compilations</h2>
    <div id="owl-demo6" class="owl-carousel">
    <?php
    $categoryId = 2; // this is the category holding your products  
      $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
     $products->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                        'image',
                           'name',
                           'short_description',
                           'sku',
                           'asin'
           ))
           ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                           Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                       Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
           ));

//$products->load();
foreach ($products as $product)  : ?>
<div class="item">
<img src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($product); ?>" alt="img"      /> 
 <?php if (!$product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($product)):?>
 <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this__('Add to Cart') ?>" 
class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product); ?>')">
<span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    items : 4,
    lazyLoad : true,
    navigation : true
  });
```

If anyone could spot what I'm missing would be great.
Thank you

Comment: This is custom page ?

Comment: This is in phtml file for my cms home page

Comment: if yes than that is because of line //$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>
function getAddToCartUrl is not available in your block class

Comment: It there any other option to add this ?

Comment: it gives fatal error on page

Comment: i have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<div id="owl-demo6" class="owl-carousel">
<?php
$categoryId = 2; // this is the category holding your products  
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                            'image',
                               'name',
                               'short_description',
                               'sku',
                               'asin'
               ))
               ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                               Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                           Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
               ));

   //$products->load();
    foreach ($products as $product)  : ?>
    <div class="item">
    <img src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($product); ?>" alt="img" /> 
 <?php if (!$product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($product)):?>
     <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this__('Add to Cart') ?>" 
  class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo  $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product); ?>')">
    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
 <?php endif;?>
 </div>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Comment: It gives the same outcome as the one I have written.Which is there is no slider only the titles of <h2> </h2> that I haven't included on here. This means it reads the cms page just not the php part.

Comment: Try with Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product)

Comment: This doesn't work as well unfortunately <?php if (!$product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($product)):?>
     <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this__('Add to Cart') ?>" 
  class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>')">
    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
 <?php endif;?>
 </div>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</div>

Comment: add your full code

Comment: I have edited the code that is how the whole slider function looks

Comment: Where is $localHelper defined ?

Comment: at the top of the page , the slider does work however when I input the button code it disapears

Comment: view your page source is there any php error ?

Comment: No errors its still loads the images but they don't appear at the site it seems like the scripts are not loaded . scripts for the slider

Comment: set  Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); in index.php file and check above again

Comment: It is set as true

Comment: comment out if before that or remove comment from line ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: I have managed to get the slider back as there was "->"missing , however the button does not appear , one step closer.

Comment: I've managed to get the button appear at the website however it doesn't add to the cart. I'm using this code   foreach ($products as $product)  { 
   ?>
    <div class="item">
 <img src="<?php echo $localHelper->getImageUrl($product); ?>" alt="img" />
 <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__() ?>" 
  class="addp" onclick="setLocation
  ('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')">
   <span><span><?php echo $this->__() ?></span></span></button>
    </div>  

  <?php
}
  ?>
</div>

Comment: use <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?> in place of $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>

Comment: That was the only issue

Comment: and adding "->" to $this->__('Add to Cart')

Comment: I would love to however need at least 15 points reputation

Comment: @MineshPatel How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f

Answer (score 0):

This due to $this of line "//$this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>"

Call .phtml file from block and use this.

```
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProduct()) ?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>
```