# How can i add "Add to Cart" options on my new products custom slider

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, slider, multiple-add-to-cart

I need to add Add to cart Options on new products custom slider on home page.

[image]

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86295/problem-with-loading-a-add-to-cart-button-into-silder

Comment: share code of new arrival phtml  template I will help you boy

Comment: am post code here

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45137/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-teja-bhagavan-kollepara

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala : am post code in chat room

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45137/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-teja-bhagavan-kollepara

Comment: not working.....

Answer (score 0):

For add to cart you need to call this code you can try this code , I dont know its working or not but you can try , But this code works on phtml file or any other php file only, dont blame me if its not work

```
<?php  
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('your_product_id');
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

This way you get add to cart block for current product.

Hope this will help